# How to show more content in dynamic link?

Tags: android, firebase-dynamic-links

I have long description that want to show while share dynamic link but I not found the way how to do it. Below this have two image, I want show like image 1 (Muslim Pro). Image 2 is mine (Dynamic Link Title). I want show like this part "Quote from the Holy Qur'an: Al-Humaza (104:1) .........."

[image: Expected Output like this]
[image: This is mine output]

This is my code the way i created dynamic link and intent share option.

```
try {
                Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                        .setLink(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=xxx.xxxx.xxxx&hl=en"))
                        .setDomainUriPrefix("https://xxx.page.link")
                        .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID).build())
                        .setSocialMetaTagParameters(
                                new DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                                        .setTitle("Dynamic Link Title")
                                        .setDescription("Dynamic Link Content")
                                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(urlLogoDynamicLink))
                                        .build())
                        .buildShortDynamicLink()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Short link created
                                    Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                                    Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();

                                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Share This Message");
                                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, shortLink.toString());
                                    c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share based"));

                                } else {
                                    // Error
                                    // ...
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //e.toString();
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you try this code? (refer to where I wrote 'change this line')

```
try {
                Task<ShortDynamicLink> shortLinkTask = FirebaseDynamicLinks.getInstance().createDynamicLink()
                        .setLink(Uri.parse("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xxxx&hl=en"))
                        .setDomainUriPrefix("https://{{yourdomainhere}}")
                        .setAndroidParameters(new DynamicLink.AndroidParameters.Builder(BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID).build())
                        .setSocialMetaTagParameters(
                                new DynamicLink.SocialMetaTagParameters.Builder()
                                        .setTitle("Dynamic Link Title")
                                        .setDescription("Dynamic Link Content")
                                        .setImageUrl(Uri.parse(urlLogoDynamicLink))
                                        .build())
                        .buildShortDynamicLink()
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<ShortDynamicLink>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<ShortDynamicLink> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    // Short link created
                                    Uri shortLink = task.getResult().getShortLink();
                                    Uri flowchartLink = task.getResult().getPreviewLink();

                                    Log.i("shortLink",shortLink.toString());
                                    Log.i("flowchartLink",flowchartLink.toString());

                                    Intent shareIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                                    shareIntent.setType("text/plain");
                                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, dataFilter.get(position).getContent());

                                    shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Check out this news article" + "\n\n" + shortLink.toString()); <-- change this line
                                    c.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Put your text here")); <-- change this line

                                } else {
                                    // Error
                                    // ...
                                }
                            }
                        });
            } catch(Exception e) {
                //e.toString();
            }
```